# Webservice in inetpub and dll in the bin

Tags: web-services

I have a webservice that gets deployed to the inetpub folder of my site. As long as my assembly deployment target is GlobalAssemblyCache everything is working fine and I can see the WSDL. But if I change the assembly deployment target to WebApplication, I can't see the WSDL anymore and I get a 400 Bad Request error. Is this just not possible or is it just a configuration error?

Answer (score 1):

Items in the GAC run with full trust whereas items in the web app /bin/ folder run with the trust level defined in the controlling web.config, which is usually minimal.  What is probably happening is that your web service is attempting to access a resource beyond what is allowed which is why it fails in /bin/ but works in the GAC

Comment: My webservice executes some stored procedures. Is this not allowed from the bin? I've also changed the trustlevel from minimal to medium.

Comment: Even Medium might not allow access to whatever resources your web service may be using.  Try placing the assembly in _app_bin instead.  If that doesn't work, you will need to either create a Custom Access Policy or put the DLL in the GAC